# Can't download file using res.sendFile() by MEAN Stack

Tags: express, mean-stack, mean.io

This is my route file xx.js

```
app.route('/api/xx/download')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    var mimetype = mime.lookup('/xx/assets/data/demo.png');

    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=demo.png');
    console.log('mimetype', mimetype);
    res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);

    res.sendFile('/xx/assets/data/demo.png')
  });
```

Below is what I got from terminal:

> mimetype image/png
>
> Sat, 13 Feb 2016 04:00:52 GMT express deprecated res.sendfile: Use res.sendFile instead at packages/custom/xx/server/routes/xx.js:32:13
>   Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/xx/assets/data/demo.png'
>       at Error (native)

But I can access this file by link: http://localhost:3000/xx/assets/data/demo.png

I am using MAC OS X EI Captian 10.11.2
My MEAN.IO version is 0.5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find an way to download file without res.sendFile(), you can using fs.createReadStream(file) or res.download(file), both can fix this problem.

## fs.createReadStream(file):

```
var mime = require('mime');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

app.route('/api/xx/download').get(function (req, res) {
    var file = __dirname + '/../../public/assets/data/demo.png';
    var filename = path.basename(file);

    var mimetype = mime.lookup(file);

    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
    console.log('mimetype', mimetype);
    res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);

    var filestream = fs.createReadStream(file);
    filestream.pipe(res);
  });
```

## res.download(file):

#### use Express res.download to make life easier

```
app.route('/api/xx/download')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    var file = __dirname + '/../../public/assets/data/demo.png';
    res.download(file);
  });
```